# How to get a line in a text through user's input?

Tags: c, file-io

I have a problem with a text file which contains a list of 55 random numbers (all in one column). What I'm trying to do is to ask the user to choose a line number so that I can bring it up but I dont know what to put in the code for this.

I'm trying to do a little game, the whole point is to ask the user to choose a line and then make him/her guess what number is hidden on that line.

Any advice would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: can you paste the code you have written so far?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) function in the standard library, it's one of the best ways to read a line of text.